# How to run node.js with timeout?

Tags: javascript, node.js

Is possible to run node.js with timeout? In my script I am connecting to external services which sometimes don't respond. Then my script hangs and the node.js process hangs.

I would like to force exit process after 5 minutes no matter if there is an error, if the process hangs or if everything is being done correctly.

It is independent of the services I use. I just want to kill the script after 5 minutes in any situation.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `process.exit` function with exit code.

```js
setTimeout(() => {
    process.exit(0);
}, 1000 * 60 * 5)
```

Comment: Should not have to be said, I do anyway ;) this exits the node process. regardless whats running inside. Without taking into account of performed tasks

Answer (score 2):

You want to set the [server.timeout](https://nodejs.org/api/http.html#http_server_settimeout_msecs_callback) property (default 0 no timeout)

Example.

```
var server = app.listen(<port>, function() {
  debug('Express server listening on port ' + <port>);
});
server.timeout = 300000; //5 minutes
```

Comment: Thanks but I'm not using node.js as a server.

Comment: can you post snippet?